Can an oscillatory field produced by a time-dependent charge distribution fall off faster than $1/r$?
An electric charge has a field that decays at large distances like $1/r^2$. A charge distribution with total charge zero, but with a nonvanishing dipole moment, has a field that decays at large distances like $1/r^3$. A charge distribution with total charge zero, total dipole moment zero, but nonzero quadrupole moment has a field that decays at large distances like $1/r^4$.
Does something similar happen with radiation? Can I have a time-dependent charge distribution that has vanishing lower "moments" in an appropriate sense, so that at large distances from the distribution the time-dependent part of the electric field is asymptotically described by $1/r^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha>1$?
For ease, let's assume the charge distribution's motion is periodic in time, and the time-dependent part of the field can be extracted as $\vec{E}_{td}(t) = \vec{E}(t) - \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \vec{E}(t') dt'$. Please note that it's ok if there's angular dependence and a space-time-dependent factor (like $\cos(kr-\omega t)$, say) in $\vec{E}_{td}(t)$. Please also note that if $\vec{E}_{td}$ has pieces going like $1/r$ and $1/r^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha>1$, I would say that the leading $r$ dependence is still $1/r$, and that such a distribution does not count as an example where the leading dependence goes like $1/r^\alpha$ with $\alpha>1$.

if the source is of finite extent then only $1/r$ is the radiating term as can be seen from energy conservation, a 3D spherical surface is  $\propto r^2,$ and also from Ignatowski's (not Jefimenko) equations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations

@hyportnex Thanks, I think this is what I was going for. I did have in mind finite-extent sources. I largely agree about the energy conservation argument (are you imagining that power via Poynting vector entering a region must on average equal power leaving a region?), but is there a nice way to tell that the $1/r$ terms in Ignatowski/Jefimenko's equations can't (approximately) cancel?

@hyportnex For example, one might imagine $\rho=0$ everywhere but with a current, maybe in a loop, leaving just the term proportional to $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec{J}$ in $\vec{E}$ -- it feels like this at different points in space could approximately cancel. Is the magic that the retarded time generically prevents the contributions from different parts of $\vec{J}$ from cancelling out?

Superposition holds in a linear wavefield and superposition is energy conserving, if there is a cancellation in one place on a far away point of the spherical surface, or better said, in one direction then the cancelled energy will show up somewhere else. An antenna has a controlled radiation pattern that is designed by the engineer to radiate the energy  in specific directions. In those direction(s) the energy spread is $1/r^2$ as expected, in other directions there is little radiation. The design is based on constructive and destructive interference in all space.

One cannot have $\rho = 0$ everywhere unless $\nabla \cdot \mathbf J = 0$ and $\mathbf {\dot J}=0$ but then there is no radiation.

@hyportnex Re: $\rho=0$ everywhere, I'm happy with that requiring $\nabla \cdot \mathbf J = 0$, but I think $\mathbf J$ can nevertheless be time-dependent (e.g. a current loop with an oscillating current)

if J is time dependent then there must be some charge accumulation somewhere.

@hyportnex Thanks for the help. I feel if $\nabla \cdot \mathbf J$ is zero, then even if $\mathbf J$ is time-dependent, there won't be charge accumulation. For example, wouldn't a current loop with current $I(t) = I_0 \cos(\omega t)$ be an example without charge accumulation but a time-dependent current?

@hyportnex I'll need to think a little bit more on superposition of time-dependent fields. I'm not sure that the energy of a superposition of fields is the sum of their energies (I might be misunderstanding what you were going for, or I'm likely forgetting a useful theorem) by virtue of cross-terms.

if $I(t)=I_0cos(ωt)$ then $\nabla J = - \dot {\rho}=0$ so $\rho = const$ no radiation (but if $I$ is in a wire then there may be surface charges on the wire and those are fluctuating...)

The short answer is no. You can already build intuition with a simpler case. Consider a scalar field obeying d'Alembert's equation:
$$
\partial_t^2\phi - \Delta\phi = 0
$$
Looking for stationary solutions converts it to Helmholtz' equation:
$$
-\omega^2\phi - \Delta\phi = 0
$$
Source terms can be added to the RHS. When performing multipole expansion, i.e. expanding $\phi$ in spherical coordinates, the radial dependence is a spherical Bessel function (using the radiating boundary condition):
$$
\phi  = \sum\phi_l^mY_l^m \\
\phi_l^m \propto h^+_l(\omega r) \sim r^{-1}
$$
Therefore, unlike electrostatics, all multipole terms have the same decay rate of $r^{-1}$, which is consistent with the usual energy balance argument. Note that this holds for $\omega\neq 0$, since for $\omega=0$ you recover the electrostatic case. The energy balance argument fails in this case since you have no energy flux, it being proportional to $\omega$ due to the radial derivation.
The same applies for electromagnetism. You just need to use vector spherical harmonics instead. In the Lorenz gauge, the vector potential satisfies the vector d'Alembert's equation, which again becomes Helmholtz' equation:
$$
-\omega^2\vec A-\Delta \vec A = 0
$$
This time you need to expand $\vec A$ as:
$$
\vec A = \sum A^r_{lm}\vec Y_{lm}+A^{(1)}_{lm}\vec\Psi_{lm}+A^{(2)}_{lm}\vec\Phi_{lm}
$$
The situation is slightly more complicated this time because the Bessel equations for $A^r,A^{(1)}$ are coupled. Diagonalizing, you find that $A^r,A^{(1)}$ are linear combinations of $h_{l-1}(\omega r),h_{l+1}(\omega r)$ and $A^{(2)}$ is proportional to $h_l(\omega r)$. The fact that you now combine $l-1,l,l+1$ is no coincidence. It comes from the spin composition between spin $l$ of the multipole and spin the of the field, $0$ for a scalar, $1$ for a vector etc. Taking the derivatives:
$$
\begin{align}
\vec E &= -i\omega \vec A-\frac1{i\omega}\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec A) & \vec B &= \nabla\times\vec  A
\end{align}
$$
the fields are again spherical Hankel functions so all still decay as $r^{-1}$. Once again, all of this is compatible with the energy balance argument with the same caveat that $\omega\neq0$.
Hope this helps.
